# How do I prevent adding more items to my flux reactor if I'm already processing a group of items

Tags: java, flux, reactor

Here is my code

```
worker = Flux.interval(ofMillis(workerInterval))
            .takeWhile(interval -> workerEnabled)
            .delaySequence(getRandomDelayDuration(INITIAL_DELAY))
            .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .flatMap(interval -> fromBlocking(this::findPractices).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable))
            .flatMapSequential(practice -> fromBlocking(() -> processPractice(practice)), 1)
            .retry(error -> logAndRetry(error, PRACTICE.name()))
            .subscribe(
                    result -> LOGGER.info("Worker finalized processing type={}", PRACTICE),
                    error -> LOGGER.error("Worker finalized with error", error)
            );



private final static Scheduler BLOCKING_IO_SCHEDULER = Schedulers.newElastic("bioThreads");

public static <T> Mono<T> fromBlocking(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(supplier)
               .subscribeOn(BLOCKING_IO_SCHEDULER);
}
```

Currently findPractices will return say 60 practices and then each practice will be operated on by processPractices (2nd flatMap).  This works fine.

My intention is that if processPractices is running and processing the 60 not to add any more practices to the buffer on subsequent run intervals.

So if processPractices is processing the first round of the 60 and is only on item number 10 and then findPractices is called because the workerInterval kicks off again, I don't want to add any more items to the buffer.

How can I do this?

Comment: create implementation of  org.reactivestreams.Subscriber; this subscriber is able to control how many items the connected Flux should generate using invocation of Subscription.request().